# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Asset '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Restored/IMG_20200115_103131.jpg' cannot be found

Tags: angular, nativescript, imagesource

Working on nativescript application and need to access image and convert it into base64.

```
.then(function(selection) {
    selection.forEach(function (selected) {
        imageSourceModule
        .fromAsset(selected)
        .then((imageSource) => {
            var imageBase64 = imageSource.toBase64String("jpg",60);
            console.log(imageBase64);
```

Comment: It's recursive, so, you might need to find the assets before you *do* anything with them. In other words, you're outer code block is operating async faster than your inner code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same problem with `fromAsset` and I solved it by doing this.

```
<application
  ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
  ...
</application>
```